# Determining primality by removing select composits

Tags: haskell, primes

Calculating many remainders for each prime and composite consumes more time.

I use a factoring function to find factors of single values.

When I use a factoring function to find lists of primes, I use a wheel.

A wheel exploits composite values punctuating an otherwise prime sequence.

The primary advantage of a wheel is reducing significantly, the candidate list and so processing.

My wheel eliminates 2, 3, 5 and 7 multiples from the a list. For the longest time, I used only elimination of 2s, 3s and 5s because the wheel list is only 8 values and simple to construct but there are just to many 7s.

Take the list of primes 11,13,17,19,23,29,31,39 and add 30 to each of the previous 8 values for subsequent values.

Take the first 55 from the list and remove the 7 multiples. The deltas will be this wheel.

What should be faster is subtraction of one list from another where the calc is compare and once only for each.

```
wl = [2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10]
-- the so-called wheel: the recurring pattern in a composite punctuated list
n7sl = scanl (+) 11 $ cycle wl -- infinite

-- short list of composits with no 2's, 3's 5's or 7's; 77%+ reduced
n7s = take 150 $ n7sl

-- diagonalize and limit the factor's composite list
lls i y = drop i.take y $ n7sl

-- substract the 1st list from the 2nd, infinite list
rms [] _ = [] -- stop when first list is exhausted
rms n@(x:xs) p@(y:ys)
    | x==y = rms xs ys
    | x>y  = y:rms n ys
    | y>x  = rms xs p

-- generate the composite list
comps [] _ _ _ _  =[] 
comps (n:ns) [] y i b = comps ns (lls (i+1) y) y (i+1) b
comps k@(n:ns) (r:rs) y i b
      | m>b  =comps ns (lls (i+1) y) y (i+1) b
      | m<=b =m:comps k rs y i b
   where m = n*r

-- the result of `comps` is not just a diagonalization but 2, top & irregular bottom
-- `comps` is maybe necessary to stop when the limit of a list is reached
-- otherwise, I was using a list comprehension which is way less complicated

-- `comps` has to many parameters so this to reduce it to 1
-- it will be subtracted the fixed length wheel numbers and the lazy wheel
comp1 n =sort $ comps n7s (lls 0 n) n 0 (11*(last.take n $ n7sl))
-- put everything together to generate primes
```

last $ rms (comp1 5000) n7sl

240641

(0.12 secs, 65,219,592 bytes)

last $ rms (comp1 10000) n7sl

481249

(0.24 secs, 143,743,944 bytes)

last $ rms (comp1 15000) n7sl

721891

(0.37 secs, 220,099,904 bytes)

Question is this better that factoring? Is there a better way to generate multiples without multiplying in `comps` or list comprehensions?

Any prime list I generate excludes 2,3,5 & 7 because they are misbehaved, irregular and to well known.

Comment: Well, I had residuals. `rms` was written to remove 7s from 2s,3s,5s list. Remove sevens: `rms` Then, in `comps` I had had trouble with the multiple. It was in a where statement b/c it occurs 3 times. Then, after fixing another problem forgot to put it back.

Answer (score 4):

You should use more `Data.List` functions - explicit recursion is hard to read.

```
comp1 y = sort [ m
  | (i,n) <- zip [0..149] n7sl
  , m <- takeWhile ((<= 11 * last (take y n7sl))) $ map (n*) $ drop i $ take n n7sl
  ]
```

Edit: Not sure whether my version fails to be equal to your original one, but here's a further refactoring of the one in your comment to get rid of some number manipulation. The `takeWhile` reflects the short-circuiting behavior of the original, explicitly recursive implementation, which uses that `bs` is ascending.

```
t = sort [ m | bs@(a:_) <- tails n7s,
  m <- takeWhile (<= 11*last n7s) $ map (a*) bs]
```

Comment: Well, thank you. Your comprehension removes a fixed amount from each factor sublist. Mine removes a varied amount according to value. Yours does not provide near enough of any. There should `n` multiples of 11 for `comp1 n`. Finally, it *must* work as a select list to subtract from the wheel to produce primes. Yours does not.

Comment: A list comprehension to produce the correct composits
`n7s = take 50 n7sl`;     
`t = sort [ m | (a,i) <- zip n7s [0..], b <- drop i n7s, m <- [a*b], m <= (11*(last n7s))]`;   
`rms t n7sl`

Comment: Well, I'm so impressed. I am also sorry. When I checked your results with mine I found a mismatch but it was because I had forgot to sort mine so I assumed yours was wrong. My bad. It is right. It is impressive and so clean.

Comment: With all the other advantages of this, it is also the fastest, if you move off the limit calculation with something like >`nt lim = sort [ m | bs@(a:_) <- tails n7s, m <- takeWhile (<= lim) $ map (a*) bs]` with `ntr = nt (11*last n7s)`. It should speed up the primes program nicely, Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

After simplifications, your *infinite* code (from your *answer*) turns out to be equivalent to

```
import Data.List (tails)
import Data.List.Ordered (minus, unionAll)

primes = ([2,3,5,7] ++) . minus n7sl . unionAll $
                  [ map (x*) xs | xs@(x:_) <- tails n7sl ]
```

The main difference is that whereas your code builds the matrix

```
> mapM_ print $ take 20 $ zip n7sl [take i n7sl | i <- [1..]]
(11,[11])
(13,[11,13])
(17,[11,13,17])
(19,[11,13,17,19])
(23,[11,13,17,19,23])
(29,[11,13,17,19,23,29])
(31,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31])
(37,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37])
(41,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41])
(43,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43])
(47,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47])
(53,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53])
(59,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59])
(61,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61])
(67,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67])
(71,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71])
(73,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73])
(79,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79])
(83,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83])
(89,[11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89])
```

by rows (in each row, the list is multiplied by the first number in the tuple), and processes it by rows -- putting them through the `unionAll` process -- the rewrite in this answer is *as if* working on the *same* matrix *by columns* (after the multiplication by the first number in the tuple, again).

Because `tails` is much less computationally demanding compared with your repeated use of `take`, and because we use `minus` from `Data.List.Ordered` package instead of your `rms` (with the flipped order of arguments), this runs much *much* faster now. Testing in GHCi:

```
> primes !! 1000000
15485867
it :: Integral a => a
(2.12 secs, 3734834160 bytes)

> primes !! 500000
7368791
it :: Integral a => a
(0.98 secs, 1765893576 bytes)

> logBase 2 (2.12 / 0.98)
1.113210610447991
```

Yes, that's a *million* primes that it now reaches, in just over 2 seconds, at about *n<sup>1.1</sup>* [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) (in n primes produced), which is quite good (the coefficient, not the time; arithmoi's code reaches the one millionth  prime in 0.1 seconds on the same computer).

This is not a sieve of Eratosthenes though. It builds the multiples not from primes, but from the 2-3-5-7-wheel enumeration.

---

For *proper* testing always compile with the `-O2` switch and run the resulting standalone executable at the shell, with `+RTS -s` run-time options (to get the time and space statistics).

Comment: You so often amaze me and you are always right.
'n7sl' is remove 1st 4 prime multiples wheel.
I had since changed the infinite function composites to (w/no take)
`umap = unionAll $ map (\n -> (n*) <$> n7sl) n7sl` ;
`take 50000 $ rms umap n7sl`
But the non-infinite above still outperforms it and yours (IDK) and makes me mad
Both mine above eschew trial division.

Comment: which non-infinite above? please give a test expression to run.

Comment: The infinite is now way faster. My misconception was remarkable, in a bad way. I thought I had to do `inits` for an infinite application. It put my factor at the end of each list so I had to use two lists and was penalized it time. `tails` is congruent with Haskell pattern matching and the factor is now at the head of each list by using `tails`. @Will Ness is the best. `inits` or `tails` diagonalizes the Cartesian product, upper or lower.

Comment: did you notice that using `n7sl` there are no non-prime numbers until 121? Your diagonal of my function is all primes. In Haskell `Data.Numbers.Primes` the `wheelSieve` take a parameter of the number of initial primes used to create the wheel and the larger wheel speeds it up. In my non-infinite list the larger wheel slowed it down. Maybe it won't in the infinite function.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking up `comps` results in simpler, more efficient, easier to control functions.

Two lists (x,y) for a Cartesian product are usual. The products are half duplicates. If each column starts with a perfect square, the duplicates are eliminated.

Then each column is generated. Each column starts with a perfect square but then must also be specifically trimmed in length. Each multiple is compared to the limititing value.

So, about 25% or less of the Cartesian product are used, that is, calculated.

`calcc` limits the value of each factor multiple it calculates just like `comps` but unlike `comps` it doesn't use an initial-factor list.
Each initial-factor squared is first on the multiple list. Each initial-factor is the `head` of each factor lists input.

I tried making `comps` use one list only instead of two. The function was short, more complicated but not faster. Two remaining problems with it were the calculation for the limit value which only needs to be calculated one time at the beginning and a problem with all such functions a glob of parameters or superflous `where` calculations. The functions need the parameters but should not be recalculated time-after-time.

`runr` passes the initial-factor to apply to itself and all other factors. The list sent to `calcc` starts with a perfect square factor value. The diagonal eliminates duplicates.

`rrunr` sarts `runr` with a length `n` factor list and the limit based on that list length.
The 11 multiples extend to `n`. Successive columns shorten to none at about `n/10`

Checking every perfect square against the limit does not save time.

I also tried `mergeAll` from Data.List.Ordered but it seemed to error around 3/4 the way down a prime list. I still have to investigate. `sort` is what I still use but the functions now let me create a single list or a list of lists for `mergeAll`.

```
calcc _ _ []= []
calcc f lim (x:xs)
        | m<= lim= m:calcc f lim xs
        | True= []
    where m= f*x

runr _ []= []
runr lim xss@(x:xs) = (calcc x lim xss)++runr lim xs

rrunr n = runr lim ds
    where ds= take n n7sl
         lim= 11*last ds
```

`last.rms (sort $ rrunr 5000) $ n7sl`

240641

(0.07 secs, 50,617,744 bytes)

`last.rms (sort $ rrunr 10000) $ n7sl`

481249

(0.18 secs, 115,282,560 bytes)

`last.rms (sort $ rrunr 15000) $ n7sl`

721891

(0.25 secs, 179,096,928 bytes)

**5/13/2019**

I tried `unionAll` instead of `mergeAll` because each sub-list is already in order. It did result in a minor speed up. `runr` produces individual sub-lists for `unionAll`.

```
runr _ []= []
runr lim xss@(x:xs) = [calcc x lim xss]++runr lim xs
```

`last $ rms (unionAll $ rrunr 10000) n7sl`

481249

(0.12 secs, 89,250,264 bytes)

`last $ rms (unionAll $ rrunr 15000) n7sl`

721891

(0.20 secs, 140,110,392 bytes)

`last $ rms (unionAll $ rrunr 20000) n7sl`

962509

(0.27 secs, 192,858,656 bytes)

I have an infinite version of this which is much simpler coding but it is a little slower.

```
mupcl _ [] = []
mupcl (x:xs) (y:ys) = [(x*) <$> y]++ mupcl xs ys

uat = unionAll.mupcl n7sl $ (\i-> (take i n7sl)) <$> [1..]
```

`take 50000 $ rms uat n7sl`

611993

(0.45 secs, 269,026,264 bytes)

I updated this because finding the nth prime is important and this can. It's still slower than the fixed just before this but has some uses not available to the fixed.
I toyed with making the sublists sequences but then found that I could generate the sublist end value and multiply it by all previous values and itself. Sequence would access the end value in about O(1) which is awesome but the end values are in one-to-one correspondence with each sublist.

The diagonal of these is just each sublist is one longer than the previous.This is the top diagonal necessary for an infinite list.

The previous functions use a bottom diagonal and a limit value. If they used the top diagonal would they end as this function? IDK

**5/27/2019**

The composite list was being traversed twice and it was driving me nuts.
I could not come up with a single function that would multiply two identical infinite lists diagonally.

I had developed one function to multiply 2s, 3s & 5s together to form the Hamming list. Saturday morning I looked at that function and followed the pattern for this function. It amazed me it worked. `unionAll` does the limiting.

```
umap = unionAll $ map (\n -> (n*) <$> n7sl) n7sl
```

But, I am such an impatient idiot the function is going through two lists, exactly what I didn't want. I have an aversion to `tails`, more like a phobia because of experience with `tails` crashing my PC in an infinite function. What I discovered the past two or three months is that `mergeAll` and `unionAll` do magic with infinite lists. They automatically limit end points. Talk about no coding. I spent so much time coding end points in this and in the Hamming numbers (which are way fast, too) that I really feel like an idiot. @Will Ness knows way more than I, too. Haskell is `pure` (no pun) magic with laziness.

```
c2 = unionAll $ map (\xs@(x:_)-> (x*) <$> xs) $ tails n7sl
```

`(minus n7sl c2) !! 1000000`

15485941

(1.55 secs, 3,545,902,888 bytes)

And now, it's way faster than the non-infinite above.

This does 75803 primes to 962509 in 0.08 and the non-infinite does 75803 to 962509 in 0.27 and uses a little more memory.

This does

`(minus n7sl c2) !! 75803`

962509

(0.08 secs, 162,030,280 bytes)

**5.30.2019**

OMG. It worked! I told @Will Ness it might, but that it would not with the non-infinite. What it is is the size of the wheel. I started calling it a wheel when I saw the deltas to create it. Mine is not a wheel because I have to generate the deltas from a column in Excel. I take 300 of `n7sl` into a column in Excel them I remove all the 11 multiples. I take the deltas of the remainder then find where it repeats.

My no 11s list is

```
n11s=[4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,14,4,6,2,10,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,10,2,4,2,12,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,6,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,6,8,6,10,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,6,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,8,4,2,4,12,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,12,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,10,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,6,6,2,6,6,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,6,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,8,6,4,2,10,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,8,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,6,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,6,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,8,4,2,6,10,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,10,6,2,4,8,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,6,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,6,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,8,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,10,2,4,6,8,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,6,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,6,6,2,6,6,4,2,10,2,10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,10,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,12,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,12,4,2,4,8,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10,6,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,10,6,8,6,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,6,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,12,2,4,2,10,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,10,2,6,4,14,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,12,2,12]
n11sl = scanl (+) 13 $ cycle n11s
```

The improvement is not stark and going any further with this would not be beneficial. `c2` modified to use `n11sl`

```
c2 = unionAll $ map (\xs@(x:_) -> (x*) <$> xs) $ tails n11sl
```

Executing it would be

`(11:(minus n11sl c2)) !! 1000000`

15485941

(1.30 secs, 2,968,456,072 bytes)

`(11:(minus n11sl c2)) !! 500000`

7368841

(0.55 secs, 1,305,594,104 bytes)